# Understanding Potential Security Risks in ERC20 transferFrom and Related Functions

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am on a mission trying to Understand Potential Security Risks in ERC20 transferFrom and Related Functions, this is the first time I really looked into the solidity or smart contracts
Context:
2 days ago, I realized that I had tokens being transferred to a bad actor address without me approving anything, the transaction was a MultiCall transaction. About 6 hours prior to this I had done a swap token swap via MetaMask which I now realize I may have approved to give permission to the contract which the bad actor is using so in turn I am trying to reverse engineer how this all works

Contract: 0x0000a1F1cE0572381189e51e6e682f41D8Dc0000

Transaction Hash: 0x42433dfecc2c355c8bbb9881a6fdbb91e0fdfa5ee0485fa64920e7010d66848b

My primary concern is to ascertain if these snippets of the contract may allow for the possibility of tokens being transferred or minted without the original owner's explicit approval.

I am interested in "public virtual override".

Am I on the right track?

```
 * @dev See {IERC20-transfer}.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
 * - the caller must have a balance of at least `amount`.
 */
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
    return true;
}

/**
 * @dev See {IERC20-allowance}.
 */
function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
    return _allowances[owner][spender];
}

/**
 * @dev See {IERC20-approve}.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
 */
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My primary concern is to ascertain if these snippets of the contract may allow for the possibility of tokens being transferred or minted without the original owner's explicit approval.
>
> I am interested in "public virtual override".

Let's start with the `public virtual override` snippet:

- `public` is a [function visibility](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/cheatsheet.html#function-visibility-specifiers) specifier. It enables to call this function from within the contract as well as from outside of this contract.
- `virtual` [modifier](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/cheatsheet.html#modifiers) enables the function to be overridden by a child contract, and `override` overrides a parent definition. But the inheritance is available only for "local" contracts before they're deployed on the same address. Another contract on a different address **cannot** override your contract.

[Event logs](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x42433dfecc2c355c8bbb9881a6fdbb91e0fdfa5ee0485fa64920e7010d66848b#eventlog) of the transaction linked in your question show that there was a previously existing approval. The ERC20 standard requires all tokens to check for approval and reject any `transferFrom()` that doesn't have an approval. So as long as the token code follows the ERC20 standard, transfer without an approval using the `transferFrom()` function is not possible.

Comment: Cheers Petr ... Looking into code a bit further into the approval as you pointed out, 
     event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
This in turn made me look at the actual address that the created contract and then found a hexadecimal code like 0x60806040 in the "Method" field on Etherscan, I assume it means that the transaction is invoking a function that is not part of the standard set of Ethereum functions like transfer, approve, etc. 
In turn has made me more interested and shall keep on learning how the world of smart contracts work...